# Is there a way to convert a JMESPath boolean to the opposite value?

Tags: boolean, jmespath

I have a JSON that has a value of true, I want to return false.

Below is an example:

```json
{"a": {"City": "Hello", "flag": false}}
```

I call `a.flag` in order to get the `false` value. However I have not been able to figure out a way to convert the `false` to `true`.

I have tried `a.flag == false` in https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html but it is not working correctly.

Comment: Posted too soon! I found out a solution.

If you wrap the JMESPATH path with parentheses then put a `!` in front, in returns the opposite.  

Ex) `! (a.flag)`

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is not working because your `false` value is not interpreted correctly in the condition `a.flag == false`.

What you are really doing when doing `a.flag == false` is that you are comparing the value of the key `false` of your JSON object to the value of `a.flag`.

A way to confirm this is to run the query:

```
foo.flag == false
```

Over those two JSON

- ```json
  {
    "false": "some value",
    "foo": {
      "city": "Brussels",
      "flag": "some value"
    }
  }
  ```

  which will return `true`
- ```json
  {
    "false": "some other value",
    "foo": {
      "city": "Brussels",
      "flag": "some value"
    }
  }
  ```

  which will return `false`

---

The correct way to compare a value to a boolean in JMESPath is to use a [literal expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions) and, so, put your boolean in backticks `` `true` ``.

With the query:

```
foo.flag == `false`
```

Over the JSON

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "city": "Brussels",
    "flag": false
  }
}
```

We get the expected: `true`

---

And of course, as you commented it, you can simply use a [not-expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#not-expressions):

```
!(foo.flag)
```