# List public hosted zones in AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am looking at the `aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name` cli call for AWS Route53 but am unable to find a way to only get the ones that are Public. Is there a way to get this information using aws cli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would look for `"PrivateZone": false`.

You can do this using [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/):

```
aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --query 'HostedZones[?Config.PrivateZone==`false`].Id'
```

Or:

```
aws route53 list-hosetd-zones-by-name --query 'HostedZones[?!(Config.PrivateZone)].Id'
```

If you want the output as Text instead of JSON, append `--output text`.

To force the results to separate lines, change `.Id` to `.[Id]`

This question has a great explanation of check for `false` values: [Is there a way to convert a JMESPATH boolean to the opposite value? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401766/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-jmespath-boolean-to-the-opposite-value)